# Como oculto algunas columnas en Datatables

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatable

tengo el siguiente código y quiero ocultar algunas de las columnas, como hago para lograr eso sin perder la data a enviar.

```
TablaUsuarios = $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({  
    "ajax":{            
        "url": "bd/crud.php", 
        "method": 'POST', //usamos el metodo POST
        "data":{opcion:opcion}, //enviamos opcion 4 para que haga un SELECT
        "dataSrc":""
    },
    "columns":[
        {"data": "id"},
        {"data": "Nombres"},
        {"data": "Apellidos"},
        {"data": "Correo"},
        {"data": "Celular"},
        {"data": "DNI"},
        {"data": "Direccion"},
        {"data": "Area"},
        {"data": "Tipo"},
        {"data": "Detalle"},
        {"data": "Fecha"},
        {"data": "Folios"},
        {"data": "Condicion"},
        {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button></div></div>"}
    ]
});
```

Soy principiante en esto, apreciaria mucho su ayuda por favor. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar la propiedad *visible* en la definición de aquellas columnas que quieres ocultar, así:

```
$('#tabla').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
        },
        {
            "targets": [ 1 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
});
```

La propiedad *visible* está establecida por defecto a *true* (como imaginarás) por lo que no necesitas ponerla en aquellas columnas que no deseas que se oculten.

Comment: Hice lo que me sugeriste, se oculto la columna, pero al intentar insertar datos desde el modal, se pierden los datos ingresados